# How can i get audio Hz 0 to 10000 in flutter App?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies, stack-overflow

I'm creating a one application in that i use audio, now i want to that audio play with user set Frequency Hz.  So I research in overall I can't find the Hz of sound in flutter.

So, Anyone have work on that So could you answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [sound_generator package](https://pub.dev/packages/sound_generator)

From their [example code](https://pub.dev/packages/sound_generator/example):

```dart
Expanded(
  flex: 8, // 60%
  child: Slider(
      min: 20,
      max: 10000,
      value: this.frequency,
      onChanged: (_value) {
        setState(() {
          this.frequency = _value.toDouble();
          SoundGenerator.setFrequency(
              this.frequency);
        });
      }),
)
```